# Software for video intro creation with many free intro templates

Tags: windows, video-editing

I have been looking for such a software for OS Windows which has many video intro templates so that I can easily customize those templates, and create my video using those templates.

Can anyone please recommend me a Windows software for video intro creation with many free intro templates?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Nero](http://www.nero.com/enu/) for several years.  It's a suite of audio/video tools that allow you to create, edit, and re-code videos.  It has add-on themes (ie. templates) that not only provide a starting point, but, also allow you to customize your video with many different effects.